# link in Google Maps marker

Tags: google-maps-markers

I cannot get a link to work in my marker.

My code is:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ draggable: false, raiseOnDrag: false, icon: image, shape: shape, map: map, url: 'http://www.google.com/', position: myLatlng36, title:"My marker" });
```

It shows the marker perfectly on the right location, but nothing happens when I click it.
I also tried adding

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  window.location.href = marker.url;
});
```

No result.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Did you test with?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

Changing 'marker' to 'this'?